# Excel Countif Date in column A is greater than column B

Tags: excel, date, countif

Columns A and B both have dates.  If the date in column A is greater than the date in the same row of column B, the row should be counted.  To add context, I am trying to count the number of rows where the completion date is past the due date.  How can this be accomplished?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add another column, make it hidden if need be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A>B:B))
```

It will sum all instances in the range where the date in column `A` is greater than that in column `B`.

You can also do this, however it needs to be entered as an array formula (`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`):

```
=SUM(IF(A:A>B:B,1,0))
```

Comment: Perfect.  In case anyone is wondering how to break it down by month, this works:

    =SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A>DATE(2012,1,1)),--(A:A<DATE(2012,2,1)),--(A:A>B:B))

Comment: @spassen Happy it helped - good luck with everything.

Answer (score 1):

Create a column that has a function to perform the comparison, e.g. `=A1 > B1`. This will give you a column that contains TRUE or FALSE for your comparison. Then you can use the COUNTIF function to count the results of this function, e.g. `=COUNTIF(C:C, "=TRUE")`.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new additional column (say C) which should have this formula =IF(A1>B1; 1; 0). Then you can add a new cell =SUM(C:C) to get the result number.