# How to count cells in a range with a value less than another cell in excel?

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

My Table looks like below

[image]

if "team1" value is less than "general" value in that month, then it has blue color,
if "team2" value is less than "general" value in that month, then it has pink color,

Now I want to count how many blue colored and how many pink colored cells on each row in a year (cells AK3 and AL3)

What is the most appropriate formula for that?

Comment: Your image attachment is not readable.

Comment: Were you able to open that link?

Comment: Yep but the image is too small, and not able to download it also

Comment: After opening the link, you can click on the image, so that the image will be zoomed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: merged two answers here:

This formula will do what you are looking for, assuming you move everything one column to the right (adding an empty column in column A):

```
=SUM(IF(C2:AK2="Team1";IF(C3:AK3 < B3:AJ3;1;0)))
```

What this does is that it first looks if you have Team1 in the column. It then proceeds to check if the data below is less than the one preceding that. It is important you have the last if as A and the others as B because otherwise it will summarise the wrong data. (For team2 you will have to change the last B3:AJ3 to A3:AI3)

Also, use shift+enter when you enter this to make sure it becomes an array formula.

---

I would highly recommend you switch your columns and rows to a more standardised form first in order to have an easier workflow with your data. I mean something like this[image: this]

I would then recommend you check out the answer for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045332/excel-countif-date-in-column-a-is-greater-than-column-b). To summarise, you gather the data in one column and then use a

```
=SUM(IF(B:B < A:A;1;0))
```

assuming you have team1 in column B and general in column A.

Comment: I cannot switch the columns and rows, I have to preserve the table structure as it is. Isn't there a way?

Comment: I just figured one out :) I will add a new answer

Comment: Better form to combine your two answers into one post.

Comment: Changed to having both of the answers in one post, hope this helps!

Answer (score 11):

You can use XL4 macros (Excel formula) to count up cells with different backcolor or even font colour in excel :) See this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887257/how-to-count-up-text-of-a-different-font-colour-in-excel). For Font color the `type_num` is `24`. And for backcolor we will use `63`

1. Open the Name Manager
2. Give a name. Say `BackColor`
3. Type this formula in Refers To `=GET.CELL(63,OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE),-1,0))` and click OK

[image]

The explanation of `=GET.CELL()` is mentioned in the above link.

Now let's say your workbook looks like this

[image]

Next put this formula in row 2.

```
=backcolor
```

[image]

Next put `=COUNTIF(A2:J2,8)` and `=COUNTIF(A2:J2,7)` in cell `C5` and `C6` respectively and you will get the total count of colors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

in `B4` put this formula:

```
=IF(B2="Team1",IF(B3<A3,1,0),IF(B2="Team2",IF(B3<OFFSET(A3,0,-1),1,0),""))
```

Then then copy it till `AJ4`.

Then in `AK3` put this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$AJ$2,"Team1",$A$4:$AJ$4,1)
```

Similarly in `AL3` put this formula.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$AJ$2,"Team2",$A$4:$AJ$4,1)
```

Hope this approach works for you.

Comment: `Excel cannot count colors` Are you sure? :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout i mean using built in formula. LOL. he doesn't want VBA. But if there is a built in function that can do, please enlighten me. :)

Comment: Yes I meant using formulas. You can use `XL4 macros (Excel formula)` to count up cells with different backcolor or even font colour in excel :) See this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887257/how-to-count-up-text-of-a-different-font-colour-in-excel). For Font color it is `24`. However I don't remember the value for `backcolor`. It sure can be found using Google :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout that's why i said enlighten us. :) LOL i already edited my answer hahaha.