# Excel Formula with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Need formula to match text from one column to text in different worksheet and count the highlighted cells. This is similar to doing a sumif, but instead of returning a numerical value in a static column, I will return the count of highlighted cells.

I have successfully written the VBA to count the highlighted cells in a given column, but now must do a match of names.  Meaning, if name in column A1:A50 matches name in Sheet2 Column J1:J52, then return a count of highlighted cells in sheet 2 column X.

Formula to count highlighted cells:  `countbycolor('sheet2'!J4:J1847,A52)`

VBA:

```
Function CountByColor(InputRange As Range, ColorRange As Range) As Long
    Dim cl As Range, TmpCount As Long, ColorIndex As Integer
    Application.Volatile
    ColorIndex = ColorRange.Interior.ColorIndex
    TmpCount = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cl In InputRange.Cells
    If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex _
        Then TmpCount = TmpCount + 1
    Next cl
    CountByColor = TmpCount
End Function
```

Comment: A1:A50 contains 50 cells to check against J1:J52 which contains 52 cells. Are you looking to see if the text in A1 is contained anywhere in J1:J52, or are you wanting to check if A1 text is equal to J1 text?

Comment: if present, then return count.

Comment: mix of both, only because I could not come up with any other way to count a colored cell other than using VBA.  If there is a way to do what I need (match name and count colored cell) and not use VBA then I will certainly give it a try.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried `Names` with the `backcolor` but only with the `font color` as shown [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887257/how-to-count-up-text-of-a-different-font-colour-in-excel) If you want, you can try and use it with [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489472/how-to-count-cells-in-a-range-with-a-value-less-than-another-cell-in-excel/20491479#20491479) and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a parameter for the criteria range and implementing `Application.Countif` should be sufficient.

```
Function CountByColorAndName(InputRange As Range, NameRange As Range, ColorRange As Range) As Long
    Dim cl As Range, TmpCount As Long, ColorIndex As Integer
    Application.Volatile
    ColorIndex = ColorRange.Interior.ColorIndex
    TmpCount = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cl In InputRange.Cells
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex and _
          cbool(application.countif(NameRange , cl.value)) then _
            TmpCount = TmpCount + 1
    Next cl
    CountByColor = TmpCount
End Function
```

Sample syntax:

```
=CountByColorAndName('sheet2'!J4:J1847, A1:A50, A52)
```

There is a little confusion as your description of the situation refers to both *Sheet2 Column J1:J52* and *'sheet2'!J4:J1847*. If this isn't appropriate, please clarify.

The [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) is actually more efficient than the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34), both on the worksheet and within VBA. This should reduce calculation load some.

```
    For Each cl In InputRange.Cells
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex then _
          if not iserror(application.match(cl.value, NameRange , 0)) then _
            TmpCount = TmpCount + 1
    Next cl
```

Comment: Thank you. I will attempt both solutions.  You were right in catching my error of description on Column J; J4:J1847 is correct.