# Microsoft Excel: How to count number of cell (with background color and conditionally formatted)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have an excel sheet, where there is a conditionally formatted col, which changes color based on the value entered.

Now I want to create a table, where it should tell the number of cells for each color. For example, if the status is marked DONE, it must be in green (based on the conditional formatting) in that case, I want my table to show numerical 1 as part of the dashboard.

I tried Get.cell function, but it seems it doesn't work when the col is conditonally formatted. Is there any other way?

So as I mentioned, I tried Get.cell function and Lambda functions, but it works only on col which is not conditonally formatted, which means, if I go by this approach, I have to manually change the color, where as the expectation is that the cell color should automatically (hence the conditional formatting) based on certain input, and that color count should be visible in the dashboard table. This is where I am stuck. Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: [For cells which are not conditionally formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489472/how-to-count-cells-in-a-range-with-a-value-less-than-another-cell-in-excel). and for cells which are conditionally formatted, you can loop through the range and check `If rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then ' For Red`?

Comment: Use countif() with the same criteria you used for the conditional formatting.