# Incorporate SUM by cell color, together with HSTACK, MAP, TEXTJOIN and LAMBDA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables where Table A is countries and Table B is driven km.

[image: Markdown data]

In B3 and C3 I have formulas I have had help creating to summarize driven km and what CW for each specific country.

**B3:**

```
=HSTACK(MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(A3:A8;"-")));LAMBDA(z;SUMPRODUCT(N(ISNUMBER($G$9:$J$13));$G$9:$J$13;N(ISNUMBER(FIND(z;$G$2:$J$6)))/MAP(G2:J6;LAMBDA(x;COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(x;"-"))))))))
```

**C3:**

```
=IFERROR(MAP(A3:A8;LAMBDA(x;TEXTJOIN("; ";;UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFS(FIND(x;$G$2:$J$6);$G$1:$J$1);3;1)))));"")
```

I have found a VBA script that I have tested and it works on it's own:

```
Function SumCellsByColor(data_range As Range, cell_color As Range)
  Dim indRefColor As Long
  Dim cellCurrent As Range
  Dim sumRes

  Application.Volatile
  sumRes = 0
  indRefColor = cell_color.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
  For Each cellCurrent In data_range
    If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
      sumRes = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cellCurrent, sumRes)
    End If
  Next cellCurrent

  SumCellsByColor = sumRes
End Function
```

My question is, can I incorporate this VBA function into the formulas in B3 and C3, to only summarize the driven km and CW based on color in a reference cell?

In this scenario I would like to be able to summarize only Blue cells, that are the same color as reference cell B12, and ignore the others and still keeping the existing functionality.

In best of worlds there would be an easy way to toggle between green and blue (checkbox?), but it's strictly a nice to have.

**Markdown data:**

| TABLE A | CW12 | CW13 | CW14 | CW15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car1 | transport | DK | DK-DE | DE |
| Car2 | SE | FI | EE | LV |
| Car3 | SE-DK-DE | DE | DK | SE |

| TABLE B | CW12 | CW13 | CW14 | CW15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car1 | transport | 150 | 200 | 150 |
| Car2 | 150 | 150 | 150 | 150 |
| Car3 | 150 | 150 | 400 | 400 |

| Countries | KM | CW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SE |  |  |
| DK |  |  |
| FI |  |  |
| DE |  |  |
| LV |  |  |
| EE |  |  |

Comment: It's maybe helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489472/how-to-count-cells-in-a-range-with-a-value-less-than-another-cell-in-excel/20491479#20491479

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

I ended up creating a third table (C) where I populated with GET.CELL from from table A.

[image]

Code in B3:

```
=BYROW(A3:A8;LAMBDA(x;SUM((IFERROR(N(+Milestones)/(1+LEN(DraftPlan)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DraftPlan;"-";"")));0)*(DraftPlanColor=VLOOKUP(C1;A12:C13;3;FALSE))*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(x;DraftPlan))))))
```

Code in C3:

```
=IFERROR(BYROW(A3:A8;LAMBDA(x;TEXTJOIN("; ";;FILTER(DraftPlanCW;BYCOL(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(x;DraftPlan))*(DraftPlanColor=VLOOKUP(C1;A12:C13;3;FALSE));LAMBDA(x;SUM(x)))))));"")
```

DraftPlan = Table A

Milestones = Table B

DraftPlanColor = Table C

GET.CELL in N2:

```
=GET.CELL(38;Sheet1!G2)
```

GET.CELL in C12:

```
=GET.CELL(38;!B12)
```

Hope this can help someone else